# NSSharingService with Animated GIFs?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm pretty new to Objective-C, but have been mostly understanding everything so far. I am stuck, however, on trying to share an animated GIF through `NSSharingService`.

I am attaching the image like so, where `image` is a string containing the URL of an animated GIF (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMmpI.gif for example):

```
NSImage *imageData = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image]];
NSArray *shareItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageData, href, nil];
NSSharingService *service = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeMessage];
service.delegate = self;
[service performWithItems:shareItems];
```

When the code is run and the message is sent, however, the image gets sent as a PNG file instead of a GIF.

My suspicion is that the image is either being flattened by `NSImage` or `NSData`, and that I need to first save the image to the disk and then attempt to send it. I am wondering, though, if this can be accomplished without that extra step of saving.

**Edit 1**:

I found a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/glebd/ImageSharingTest/) which was attempting to answer a similar problem. A solution was never found, however, but the last bit of advice was:

> However, when I add an `NSAttributedString` with a GIF attachment to
>   `NSSharingServicePicker`, the shared image is not animated. I can't
>   add the wrapper `RTFD` data to the picker, as it can only share
>   objects that support `NSPasteboardWriting` protocol, and the `RTFD` is
>   returned as `NSData`.
>
> Copying `RTFD` data to pasteboard as `NSRTFDPboardType` works and
>   preserves animation

Would it be possible to convert the GIF to an `RTDF` object, copy it to the pasteboard, retrieve the pasteboard item, then share that object? Or is it impossible to preserve animation with `NSSharingService`?

**Edit 2**:

As @Cocoadelica mentioned in the comments, I'm wondering if `CoreImage` might be required to preserve animation. I attempted saving the GIF file to the hard drive first, then loading it into `NSImage`, but it once again converted it into a static PNG.

This is very, very, very frustrating.

Comment: I'm only familiar with iOS and GIF handling but the likelihood is that NSImage is doing it. NSData does;t care about types it just takes in the bytes. You may need to drop down to CoreImage to keep the GIF format and get the data through that.

Comment: @Cocoadelica So there's no straightforward way to retain the type with `NSImage`? I haven't dealt with `CoreImage` yet, so I'm not entirely sure what I'd be looking to do with it.

Comment: As I say I'm more familiar with UImage but essentially it's a container for image data from which you can produce representations of the image in different formats. It doesn't have a single 'type'. When you deal with CoreImage, it;s a C-based API and you're handling the image file as it was sourced, so a gif is a gif. There are even tools in there for making a gif from individual frames which could be UI/NSImages.

Comment: I worked with animated GIFs and while it's possible to receive handle and store them in Cocoa, the only way to really view them is in a web view, the standard image view objects don't support GIF animation. IF it's static GIF's then things are easier just remember that your NSImage is a wrapper around the image data that can output whatever you want.

Comment: @Cocoadelica I don't even need to display it though, just attach the raw gif to NSSharingService to send. I'm not entirely sure if I can send core animation data with NSSharingService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting a response via the Cocoa-dev mailing list. Basically, you need to attach an `NSURL` directly linking to the file. It doesn't work for external images, and `NSImage` is never used:

```
NSString *fileUrl = @"http://i.imgur.com/V8w9fKt.gif";
NSString *fileName = [fileUrl lastPathComponent];
NSURL *saveUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@", NSTemporaryDirectory()]];
saveUrl = [saveUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
// Write image to temporary directory
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileUrl]];
[data writeToURL:saveUrl atomically:YES];

// Attach the raw NSURL pointing to the local file
NSArray *shareItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:saveUrl, @"Text", nil];

// Open share prompt
NSSharingService *service = [NSSharingService sharingServiceNamed:NSSharingServiceNameComposeMessage];
service.delegate = self;
[service performWithItems:shareItems];
```

I then implemented didShareItems and didFailToShareItems so that I could remove the file after sharing was complete:

```
- (void)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService didShareItems:(NSArray *)items{
    NSString *path = items[0];
    [self removeFile:path];
}

...

- (void)removeFile:(NSString *)path{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
}
```

And for those struggling, I found the following method was required for everything to work properly:

```
- (NSWindow *)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService sourceWindowForShareItems:(NSArray *)items sharingContentScope:(NSSharingContentScope *)sharingContentScope{
    return self.window;
}
```

I realize some of that code is improper (my `URLWithString` creation is counterintuitive, but I'm learning), but this should get those struggling a starting point.